# Promises in a broker-client communication using 0MQ

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq, promise, broker

I am attempting to develop a broker that serves as a proxy for communication between some workers and clients using 0MQ. The task was relatively simple to do without promises, but due to the fact that I am inexperienced with the use of promises I am unable to understand how to implement promises in this example.

Code for Broker:

```
//Broker that serves as proxy for workers and clients
var zmq = require('zmq');
var frontend = zmq.socket('router');
var backend = zmq.socket('router');
var Q = require('q');

frontend.bindSync('tcp://*:8001');
backend.bindSync('tcp://*:8002');

var frontendOn = Q.nbind(frontend.on, frontend);
var backendOn = Q.nbind(backend.on, backend);

var requestFrontend = frontendOn('message').then(function(){
console.log("Message received");
});
var requestBackend = backendOn('message').then(responseBackend);

...
```

Code for client:

```
//Client program that communicates with broker

var zmq = require('zmq')
var requester = zmq.socket('req');
var Q = require('q');

var arguments = process.argv.splice(2);

//Connect with broker
requester.connect(arguments[0]); 

console.log("Connected successfully to broker");

//Send message to broker
requester.send(arguments[1]);   

console.log("Message sent to broker");

...
```

The client connects to the broker, sends the message but the message is not processed by the broker. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with ZeroMQ but [from the docs](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) I assume that `on` seems to be an event subscription mechanism, and not a NodeJS-style asynchronous operation accepting callback. It may fire more than once, right?

If this is the case, why do you want to use promises at all? They seem like the wrong abstraction for this particular situation.

**Promises represent operations that finish or fail once, not asynchronous streams of values.**

Even if

```
var requestFrontend = frontendOn('message').then(function(){
  console.log("Message received");
});
```

worked, it wouldn't be of any benefit to you because `then` would only be called once.
I assume that's not what you wanted.

If you're looking for a way to filter, map, merge or throttle asynchronous sequences, you can look into [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) which does exactly that (it also interfaces with promises). But promises shouldn't, and can't be used as substitute for events that fire more than once.

---

On the other hand, **if the message really does come only once**, I agree it's best to use promises to abstract it away. However, **[`nfbind`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdenodeifynodefunc-args) or `nbind` won't work here** because they require `function(err, result)`-style callbacks, and you have `function(result)`.

Here's what I suggest you use instead:

```
function promiseOneMessage(queue) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  queue.on('message', deferred.resolve);
  queue.on('error', deferred.reject);

  return deferred.promise;
}

var requestFrontend = promiseOneMessage(frontend)
  .then(function (message) {
    console.log("Message received", message);
  })
  .done();

var requestBackend = promiseOneMessage(backend)
  .then(responseBackend)
  .done();
```

Comment: Hence `Q.nbind(frontend.on, frontend);` ? Each event is a promise on its value.

Comment: @Benjamin: What exactly do you mean? Promise can finish only once, but the handler won't go anywhere, so zeromq will try to invoke the handler to no avail. Of course you can create a promise on each message, but I don't think that's what the OP wants. *Moreover*, zeromq `on` is *not* a NodeJS-style function: its callback signature is `function(message)` and not `function(err, result)`. Thus any promise will fail.

Comment: Ah, if that's the case in zeromq's on you might want to clarify that in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarifications. Regarding if the message event may fire more than once, let me go through the communication process. Each client that is running only sends 1 message to the broker. The broker then forwards the message to a worker that sends a modified version of the message back to the broker. But this time to the backend. So really the event is only fired once for the frontend (coming from the client) and another time for the backend (coming from the worker).

Comment: @ashe: I see. I'll amend the answer shortly.

Comment: @ashe: I amended my answer.

Comment: @Dan Thanks I'll give it a shot and get back to you!

Comment: @ashe: Sure. Note that I added `done` call—so you don't swallow errors.

Comment: @DanAbramov Works perfectly! Although I'm still a little unclear as to why nbind wouldn't actually work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ashe: It doesn't work because `nbind` expects NodeJS-style callback that accepts `error` as first argument, and `result` as second. So when `on` executes the callback, it passes `message` as first parameter. But **`nbind` thinks first parameter will be an error (NodeJS-style)**, so it marks promise as **failed** with `message` as the reason. That's why `then` never executes in your example, but I'm sure if you add `catch` to it, that's where the message will go. Cheers!

Comment: Ahh ok. I though that was only applicable for nfbind and not for nbind. Understood.

Comment: @ashe: `nbind` is exactly like `nfbind`, but allows to specify the context (`this` object).

Comment: @DanAbramov What would be the correct way of extracting the message at the broker? It doesn't seem to be in arguments as before.

Comment: @ashe: Supposedly it will be passed to `deferred.resolve`, and from there as a first argument to the function you passed to `then`. I clarified the example.